# How to avoid this memory leak caused by DataFrame.sum() in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, memory-leaks

I'm working with a Pandas data frame, which is not small, but arguably huge. My program counts occurrences of words and then I want to add together the occurrences of the same words using.

`tokenTable = tokenTable.groupby('Word').sum().reset_index();`

The problem is that it eats my memory to the level that my computer freezes and shuts down in 10 minutes, which is not really pleasant, but what is more of a problem is that it doesn't do the summing.

After some debugging, and research on the web, I've discovered that the sum() function is causing the problem, there is an error related to this on GitHub: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16788

I tried the recommendations there, but I have the latest version of bottleneck, and also tried the code snippet on the page, namely:

```
y = tokenTable.values.sum(axis=0)   # requires < 4 GB of memory
y = pd.Series(y, index=tokenTable.columns)
```

But neither this helped me in avoiding the memory leak, and I'm basically out of ideas what could be causing it.

Could you help providing me either an alternative code or some configuration update so that I'm able to do the summing preferably not using more than 4GB of memory?

**The size of the dataframe:**

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 26208 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Bottom     26208 non-null object
Middle     26208 non-null object
Picture    26208 non-null object
Top        26208 non-null object
Word       26208 non-null object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 1.2+ MB
```

**Versions of relevant modules**

numpy 1.13.1, pandas 0.20.3, scipy 0.19.1, bottleneck 1.2.1, spyder 3.1.4

**More on the counting, sample data**

On the example above each word has a Bottom-Middle-Top column, but one word can occur multiple times. Basically, I want to add together the Bottom-Middle-Top and the picture columns for all words so I have a word count in B-M-T and a list of picture file names in the picture column. That is what my groupby('Word').sum() did for me with smaller data.

```
  Bottom Middle                                            Picture Top  \
0      0      0  0    3dad916f29adacccb660ca46ac93cadf_best.jpg...   1   
0      0      0  0    3dad916f29adacccb660ca46ac93cadf_best.jpg...   1   
0      0      0  0    3dad916f29adacccb660ca46ac93cadf_best.jpg...   1   
0      0      1  0    b0cad74387ae31688fe3584746068871_best.jpg...   0   
0      0      1  0    b0cad74387ae31688fe3584746068871_best.jpg...   0   

            Word  
0           100%  
0  cotton~Collar  
0           Hood  
0        Pleated  
0          Crepe
```

Comment: Can you paste sample data and expected output?

Comment: Added to the end of the post